# How Do I Solve SDK compatibility and StyleSheet Error

Tags: react-native, expo

Please I will appreciate an assistance. I published my React Native Expo Go application and attempting to launch the app from the email url link provided by Expo but I got the following Error :

```
This project uses SDK 43.0.0, but this version of Expo Go only supports he following SDKs, 46.0.0, 47.0.0, 48.0.0
```

After exploring the stackoverflow, I quickly do "npm install" to update and my project Expo got upgraded to 48.0.0 successfully and I published the project again but this time the publish could not complete and it shows the following error:

```
Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 7.0.0, 8.0.0, 9.0.0, 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, 13.0.0, 14.0.0, 15.0.0, 16.0.0, 
17.0.0, 18.0.0, 19.0.0, 20.0.0, 21.0.0, 22.0.0, 23.0.0, 24.0.0, 25.0.0, 26.0.0, 27.0.0, 28.0.0, 29.0.0, 30.0.0, 31.0.0, 
32.0.0, 33.0.0, 34.0.0, 35.0.0, 36.0.0, 37.0.0, 38.0.0, 39.0.0, 40.0.0, 41.0.0, 42.0.0, 43.0.0

Warning: Unable to resolve manifest assets. Icons might not work. Unable to perform cache refresh for 
C:\Users\l9\AppData\Local\Expo\schema-48.0.0.json: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND exp.host.
```

Even when I use "expo start" to first run the upgraded project app on my computer android emulator I still got the same error. Please what am I doing wrong because I do not even know how to approach this error.

I copied the project to another folder before upgrading expo and when I ran the previous project it loads(no compilation error from any .js file) well and show the SplashScreen of the app without any compilation error but when about to show login screen it would display the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: StyleSheet

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

The problem with the previous project before I upgraded the expo version to 48.0.0 was that the Expo Go app did not run it because the SDK for it was 43.0.0 and the Expo Go app is 48.0.0 so it complained of version incompatibility. I did not have any StyleSheet I used without importing it first from react native because if I did it could have been pointed out.

Thank you

Comment: for upgrade SDK version you must use "expo upgrade" command